# Smooth Transition Between 2 Android OpenGL GLSurfaceView Activities

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity, glsurfaceview

I have 2 `Activitiy`s which use `OpenGL` for drawing. At a transition from one activity to the next I get an unsightly empty screen filled with my `OpenGL` clear colour (so its not as bad as a black screen).

I wish to effectively transition seamlessly between `Activity`s, but there are several high load regions when a `GLSurfaceView` is created. The main issue is texture loading as this is slowest.

Is there anyway to double buffer between `Activity`s so that the last `Activity` view is frozen until I explicitly tell my next `Activity` to draw? I want transitions to be seamless?

Moving everything into one `GLSurfaceView` instance isn't really an option I want to consider.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setRenderMode( RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY)` in your GLSurfaceView, so the surface only will be redraw when you call `requestRender()`.
This way, anything that you draw before calling another surface view will only be cleared when you request a new draw.
You can back to the continuous drawing by setting render mode as `RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY`.

Comment: I'll give this a try but my gut feeling is i will still get a black transition. I'll report back once i have tested. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm afraid this didnt resolve the issue for me. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to do it in Android 2.x because of its OpenGL ES. Also, it is not recommended that you use two OpenGL in one applications if you are in render continously. If so, to control them easily, you will need RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY.

If you use it in Android 4.x, TextureView is an optional to do it.

TextureView is as same as GLSurfaceView but with View compatible, it means that you can use ViewAnimation for TextureView.